# Excel addin: values are not updated on the worksheet after ctx.sync

Tags: office-js

```
 Excel.run(function (ctx) {

                // Create a proxy object for the active sheet
                var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                var sampleRange2 = sheet.getRange(sampleRange.address);
                sampleRange2.load();

                return ctx.sync()
                    .then(function () {

                        for (var i = 0; i < suggestion.OutputCellList.length; i++) {

                            if (!sampleRange2.values[i][sampleRange.values[0].length - 1]) {
                                sampleRange2.values[i][sampleRange.values[0].length - 1] = suggestion.OutputCellList[i];

                            }
                        }

                        sampleRange2.format.fill.color = "blue";
                        sampleRange2.format.font.bold = false;

                    })
                    .then(ctx.sync)
            })
```

The code simply updates values of the last column of the target range and applies new formatting. After ctx.sync, the new formatting works, but not the values. Debugging shows the values array has all new values correctly. But, all the target cells on the worksheet remain blank even after sync. Any possible cause?

Answer (score 2):

Setting 2D-arrays is a little different than regular properties.  You have to set them "wholesale", so that the property-set of the object gets triggered.  Otherwise, you're effectively manipulating a JavaScript array, but the object has no awareness of the change.

Simplest solution (though it feels hacky) is to stick

```
sampleRange2.values = sampleRange2.values;
```

right after your for-loop.  The problem with that solution is that some developer who looks at this code might go *"huh, why did they possibly do that"*, and erase the statement as something redundant, even though it carries great value.

The less hacky-looking solution is, before your for-loop, declare a new variable:

```
var newValues = sampleRange.values;
```

Then operate on your newValues array, and then set

```
sampleRange.values = newValues;
```